# Pandas DataFrame Groupby and Reforming

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a question on using groupby() with the following shortened example of pandas dataframe. What I am trying to achieve here is to add-up the 'amount' value per 'date' for each 'store_id' while keeping the 'days_of_week' and 'holiday' column.

```
    store_id    date        amount  days_of_week    holiday
0   0           2017-11-14  100     1               0
1   0           2017-11-14  -100    1               0
2   1           2017-11-14  122     1               0
3   1           2017-11-19  55      6               1
4   2           2017-11-19  11      6               1
5   2           2017-11-19  32      6               1
```

So the result should look like the following.

```
    store_id    date        amount  days_of_week    holiday
0   0           2017-11-14  0       1               0
1   1           2017-11-14  122     1               0
2   1           2017-11-19  55      6               1
3   2           2017-11-19  43      6               1
```

I've tried dropping the 'day_of_week' and 'holiday' column, then using groupby() to get the sum per each date so far. But that is far from achieving my desired form of result.

```
train = train.drop(columns=['days_of_week', 'holiday'])
train.groupby(['store_id', 'date'])['amount'].sum()
```

Is there any other methods that I'm unaware of to easily get the second example form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the panda aggregate function. see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html

The following code should work for your case

```
df_sum = df.groupby(['date','store_id']).agg({'amount':'sum', 'days_of_week': 'first', 'holiday': 'first' }).reset_index()
print(df_sum)

        date  store_id  amount days_of_week  holiday
0 2017-11-14         0     0.0            1        0
1 2017-11-14         1   122.0            1        0
2 2017-11-19         1    55.0            6        1
3 2017-11-19         2    43.0            6        1
```